# Difference between a "jta-datasource" and a " resource-local " datasource?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jta

The terms "jta-datasource" and "resource-local datasource" are a little vague to me. I'm putting down what I am understanding ( or assuming ) and I'd like you to say where I'm right / wrong.

- The same database can be referred to as a jta-datasource or as a resource local datasource
- If mentioned as jta-datasource, then the beans / other classes can use JTA. Hence, UserTransaction interface
- Cannot use [CMT](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) / [BMT](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html) if the datasource is resource local
- If mentioned as resource local datasource, transactions are not JTA aware. Code can use EntityTransaction interface but not UserTransaction interface

Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> The terms "jta-datasource" and "resouce-local datasource" are a little vague to me.

I guess you actually refer to the `jta-datasource` and `non-jta-datasource` elements. In short:

- if the transaction type of the persistence unit is *JTA*, the `jta-datasource` element is used to declare the JNDI name of the JTA data source that will be used to obtain connections. This is the common case.
- if the transaction type of the persistence unit is *resource-local*, the `non-jta-data-source` should be used to declare the JNDI name of a non-JTA data source.

> - The same database can be referred to as a jta-datasource or as a resource local datasource

This is correct. And I didn't mention that just above but some providers even allow to declare both a `jta-datasource` **and** a `non-jta-datasource` and use the later for optimized reading through non-JTA connections (i.e. that won't be associated to an ongoing JTA transaction).

> - If mentioned as jta-datasource, then the beans / other classes can use JTA. Hence, UserTransaction interface.

The first part is correct, the last part not entirely. From the EJB 3.0 spec, section **13.3.4 Enterprise Beans Using Container-Managed Transaction Demarcation**:

> The enterprise bean’s business methods [...] must not attempt to obtain or use the `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` interface.

And section **16.12 UserTransaction Interface**:

> The container must not make the `UserTransaction` interface available to the enterprise beans that are not allowed to use this interface.

In other words, the `UserTransaction` interface is not available to CMT enterprise beans.

> - Cannot use CMT / BMT if the datasource is resource local

The wording is a bit confusing here but I'd say that this not strictly correct. From the JPA 1.0 specification, section **§ 5.5 Controlling Transactions**:

> An application-managed entity manager may be either a JTA entity manager or a resource-local entity manager.
>
> ...
>
> Both JTA entity managers and resource-local entity managers are required to be supported in Java EE web containers and EJB containers. Within an EJB environment, a JTA entity manager is typically used.

And **section 6.2.1.2 transaction-type**

> The `transaction-type` attribute is used to specify whether the entity managers provided by the entity manager factory for the persistence unit must be JTA entity managers or resource-local entity managers. The value of this element is `JTA` or `RESOURCE_LOCAL`. A transaction-type of JTA assumes that a JTA data source will be provided — either as specified by the `jta-data-source` element or provided by the container. In general, in Java EE environments, a `transaction-type` of `RESOURCE_LOCAL` assumes that a non-JTA datasource will be provided. In a Java EE environment, if this element is not specified, the default is JTA.

So you CAN use an *application managed entity manager* which can be a *resource-local entity manager* (you must inject an `EntityManagerFactory` to get the EM from it in that case) and it won't be part of a JTA transaction. See [this (very interesting) discussion](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=358150&tstart=0).

> - If mentioned as resource local datasource, transactions are not JTA aware. Code can use EntityTransaction interface but not UserTransaction interface

Again, the wording is a bit confusing but I'd say that this is correct.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you so much for taking time and explaining it all so clearly !!!  I see now that we use the term "resource local EntityManager" and not "resource local datasource". Yes I meant non-jta-datasource when I said "resource local datasource".

This is how I understand now:

JTA / RESOURCE_LOCAL   --> Transaction Type of the EntityManager. Determines who controls the underlying transaction. whether JTA / EntityTransaction API 

JTA EntityManger:
Container manages this EntityManager. Involves in JTA transactions. A JTA transaction can be either a CMT or a BMT. Can be used in managed classes.

Comment: Resource-Local EntityManager:

The EnityManager is not managed by the container.

Involves in Non-JTA transactions.

EntityTransaction API is used.

Can use in POJOs 

For BMT, UserTransaction always uses a jta-datasource and cannot use a non-jta-datasource
Likewise for CMT too, the container could only use a jta-datasource

Comment: @stratwine: You're welcome, glad you found it helpful (and your understanding looks correct). Regarding the wording, I didn't mean to be picky but since the spec defines a very precise (and subtle) terminology, using it makes the communication easier, which is why I insisted a bit about that (and I'd recommend to read the sections I quoted partially).

Comment: @PascalThivent The link to "this (very interesting) discussion" doesn't work, do you mean the following?

https://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/users/archive/2009-07/message/1120