# What does the "Use Java Transaction APIs" checkbox do in Netbeans persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, netbeans, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

In Netbeans in the persistence.xml there is a checkbox called "Use Java Transaction API" this changes the xml from:

```
<persistence-unit name="PUNAME-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

To:

```
<persistence-unit name="PUNAME-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
```

Is this for CMT vs BMT?

Comment: You might find this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217586/difference-between-a-jta-datasource-and-a-resource-local-datasource) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the JPA2 specification says about this attribute:

> The transaction-type attribute is used to specify whether the entity
> managers provided by the entity manager factory for the persistence
> unit must be JTA entity managers or resource-local entity managers.
> The value of this element is JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL. A transaction-type
> of JTA assumes that a JTA data source will be provided—either as
> specified by the jta-data-source element or provided by the container.
> In general, in Java EE environments, a transaction-type of
> RESOURCE_LOCAL assumes that a non-JTA datasource will be provided. In
> a Java EE environment, if this element is not specified, the default
> is JTA. In a Java SE environment, if this element is not specified,
> the default is RESOURCE_LOCAL.

And here is what it says about JTA and resource local entity managers:

> JTA EntityManagers
>
> An entity manager whose transactions are controlled
> through JTA is a JTA entity manager. A JTA entity manager participates
> in the current JTA transaction, which is begun and committed external
> to the entity manager and propagated to the underlying resource
> manager.
>
> Resource-local EntityManagers
>
> An entity manager whose transactions are
> controlled by the application through the EntityTransaction API is a
> resource-local entity manager. A resource-local entity manager
> transaction is mapped to a resource transaction over the resource by
> the persistence provider. Resource-local entity managers may use
> server or local resources to connect to the database and are unaware
> of the presence of JTA transactions that may or may not be active.